# How to have .AddJsonBody ignore nulls in object in C# utilizing RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, jsonserializer

I'm having issues with getting my JsonBody to parse without the null fields so I just perform updates on fields I want within the object. I know I can get around this by just passing the values I want as a new object but was trying to have it accept whichever values weren't set to null in the object only.

```
var request = new RestRequest($"/example", Method.Patch)
            .AddJsonBody(object);
        

var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Attempted to add the below when I was creating my RestClient but it didn't the s.UseSystemTextJson portion for me to be able to add the JsonSerializerOptions

```
var client = new RestClient(
    options, 
    configureSerialization: s => s.UseSystemTextJson(new JsonSerializerOptions {...})
);
```

Also, attempted to add [JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)] to the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
  IgnoreNullValues = true
};
```

It will exclude null values from the JSON.

Pass it to the `Serialize()`

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(object, jsonOptions);
```

Create request like :

```
var request = new RestRequest($"/example", Method.Patch)
        .AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```